# C++ give me strange result

Tags: c++, visual-studio, integer, windows-10, visual-studio-2019

I have a very strange result running the following C++ code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int c[]={49,46,48,46,51};
    int p=0;
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
         p =p*100+c[i];

    cout << "Hello World! p=" <<p<< endl;
    return 0;
}
```

> Hello World! p=651517355

However, the expected results is 4946484651.

Even if I change the data type to long integer, the same wrong result was given.

My environment is,

```
windows 10, Qt Creator 4.14.1 (Qt 5.15.2 MSVC2019 64bit)
cl -c -nologo -Zc:wchar_t -FS -Zc:rvalueCast -Zc:inline -Zc:strictStrings -Zc:throwingNew -Zc:referenceBinding -Zc:__cplusplus -Zi -MDd -W3 -w34100 -w34189 -w44996 -w44456 -w44457 -w44458 -wd4577 -wd4467 -EHsc /Fddebug\aa.vc.pdb -DUNICODE -D_UNICODE -DWIN32 -D_ENABLE_EXTENDED_ALIGNED_STORAGE -DQT_QML_DEBUG -I..\aa -I. -I..\..\..\Qt\5.14.0\msvc2017\mkspecs\win32-msvc -Fodebug\ @C:\Users\guest\AppData\Local\Temp\main.obj.20080.15.jom
main.cpp
```

Comment: `4296596394` is too much for typical 32-bit integer to hold, you get an integer overflow. `long long p` might do what you want (it's range is something about 10^18)

Comment: when uncertain you can check ranges via `std::numeric_limits<T>::max()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On many platforms (including yours, it would appear), both `int` and `long int` are 32-bit integers, which cannot hold the value `4946484651`. (The Standard mandates only that `long int` be *no shorter than* `int` and *at least* 32 bits wide.)

You need to use `long long int` for `p` or, better still, use the explicit `int64_t` type:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>

int main()
{
    int c[] = { 49,46,48,46,51 };
    int64_t p = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        p = p * 100 + c[i];

    std::cout << "Hello World! p=" << p << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Hello World! p=4946484651
```

Comment: It is not mandatory that an implementation support `int64_t`.   Support of `long long` is mandatory since C++11.   (Before C++11, neither were required, although some implementations supported one or the other as a non-standard extension).

Comment: @Peter I'm not sure which (if any) Standard introduced it, but isn't `long long int` now *mandated* to be at least 64 bits? I'm looking through various Drafts... Seemingly, it was C++11.

Comment: So, maybe using `long long int` is "safer" than `int64_t`. Seems counter-intuitive, though. Strangely, [this cppreference page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer) implies that `int64_t` is *optional* but that `int_least64_t` is not!

Comment: Counter-intuitive or not, `long long int` is required and `int64_t` is optional (several fix-width types, including `int64_t`, are only required if the implementation directly supports the type - that wording leaves it up to the implementation).   Both `long long` types and the fixed-width types were introduced in C++11.

Comment: For correctness, it's better to explicitly `#include <cstdint>` (and not to rely on the fact that `std::int64_t` may be indirectly pulled in via <iostream>), I think.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int c[] = { 49,46,48,46,51 };
    int64_t p = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        p = p * 100 + c[i];

    cout << "Hello World! p=" << p << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Because you keep same large(greater that 2^32) number in p it overflows.